# Internal Error 500 when using Flask and Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am working on a small college project using Raspberry Pi. Basically, the project is to provide an html interface to control a sensor attached to the Pi. I wrote a very simple Python code attached with a very basic html code also. Everything is done in this path /var/www/NewTest. However everytime I try to access it throws a 500 internal error. I tried simple "Hello World" examples that worked with me and tried to do this example the same way but didn't work.

led.py

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

ledr = LED(17)
ledg = LED(27)
ledb = LED(22)


@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/red/')
def red():
  ledr.off()
  ledg.off()
  ledb.off()
  ledr.on()
  return ' '

@app.route('/green/')
def green():
  ledr.off()
  ledg.off()
  ledb.off()
  ledg.on()
  return ' '

@app.route('/blue/')
def blue():
  ledr.off()
  ledg.off()
  ledb.off()
  ledb.on()
  return ' '

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

led.conf

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName 10.0.0.146

    WSGIDaemonProcess led user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www/NewTest/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/NewTest/led.wsgi

    <directory /var/www/NewTest>
        WSGIProcessGroup led
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>

<title>Test</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>

<a href="/red/">RED</a> <br/>
<a href="/green/">GREEN</a><br/>
<a href="/blue/">BLUE</a>
```

any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in led.conf. The user needs to be pi.

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName 10.0.0.146

    WSGIDaemonProcess led user=pi group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www/NewTest/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/NewTest/led.wsgi

    <directory /var/www/NewTest>
        WSGIProcessGroup led
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</virtualhost>
```